# How to fix a React search filter that doesn't update on backspace

Tags: reactjs

**The issue:**

I'm trying to create a search filter in React, based on first and last name. The search is working when I initially type a matching name, but the results don't update whenever I backspace. Component and additional details included below:

```
class People extends Component {
    state = {
        people: [],
        searchValue: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/metadata.json').then(response => {
            const updatedPeople = response.data.map(person => {
                return {
                    ...person
                };
            });
            this.setState({ people: updatedPeople });
        }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
    }

    searchHandler = (event) => {
        let searchResults = this.state.people;
        searchResults = searchResults.filter(result => {
            return result.name.toLowerCase().search(
                event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });

        this.setState({
            people: searchResults,
            searchValue: event.target.value.toLowerCase()
        }, () => console.log('state', this.state))
    };

    render() {
        let people = this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
            return (
                <Person
                    key={index}
                    name={person.name} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input
                    type="search"
                    value={this.state.searchValue}
                    onChange={this.searchHandler} />
                <div className={classes.People}>
                    {people}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I've tried**:

1. creating a search handler that filters names matching `event.target.value` and updating state based on the results.
2. adding a second property to state, `filteredPeople`, to store the filtered list of names while keeping the original list in `state.people`. However, I ran into issues reconciling these two
3. writing a function to check the search query and return a value based on whether there's a match, but I questioned if this was needed given the check I'm already doing in searchHandler.

What do I need to do to get my search filter fully functional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two arrays one for original data and one for filtered data

```
state = {
    people: [],
    searchValue: '',
    filteredPeople: [],
};

handleSearch = event => {
  const search = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

  this.setState({
    searchValue: search,
    filteredPeople: this.state.people.filter(
     item =>
      (item.lastname && item.lastname.toLowerCase().includes(search)) ||
      (item.name && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
    )
   });
};
```

Then render your filtred array

```
let people = this.state.filteredPeople.map((person, index) => {
  return (
    <Person
      key={index}
      name={person.name} />
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const people = [{
  name: 'Isaac', lastname: 'Jacobs'
},
{
  name: 'Peter', lastname: 'Micheal'
},
{
  name: 'John', lastname: 'Snow'
}
]

class Person extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{`${this.props.name} - ${this.props.last}`}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    people: people,
    searchValue: '',
    filteredPeople: people,
  };

  searchHandler = event => {
    const search = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  
    this.setState({
      searchValue: search,
      filteredPeople: this.state.people.filter(
        item =>
          (item.lastname && item.lastname.toLowerCase().includes(search)) ||
          (item.name && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
      )
    });
  };

  render() {

    let people = this.state.filteredPeople.map((person, index) => {
      return (
        <Person
          key={index}
          last={person.lastname}
          name={person.name} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="search"
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          onChange={this.searchHandler} />
        {people}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need a second property of state to contain the filtered list of people

```
state = {
    people: [],
    searchValue: '',
    filtered_people: []
};

searchHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({filtered_people: [] })

    let searchResults = [...this.state.people];

    searchResults = searchResults.filter(result => {
        return result.name.toLowerCase().search(
            event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

    this.setState({
        filtered_people: searchResults,
        searchValue: event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    }, () => console.log('state', this.state))
};
```

Clearing the filtered_people array on every onChange event is how you can delete the results on a backspace.

Comment: you don't have to clear anyhthing, filter function will return everything when there's only space in the input.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter